# Exec form of RUN instruction in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

For the below "shell" form of RUN instruction, what would be the "exec" form?

```
RUN echo `uname -rv` > $HOME/kernel-info
```

I tried below, its giving the error, `cat: can't open '/root/kernel-info': No such file or directory`

```
RUN ["echo","uname", "-rv", ">", "$HOME","/kernel-info" ]
```

Comment: RUN ["echo","\`uname -rv\`", ">", "$HOME/kernel-info" ]

Comment: Still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using output redirection and environment variable substitution which are both done by the shell. So you need a shell to run. If you prefer the exec form, you need to run the shell yourself, like this

```
RUN [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo `uname -rv` > $HOME/kernel-info" ]
```

Comment: (The shell form converts to exactly this under the hood.)

Comment: Thank you Hans - I see the file is getting generated now. How do I use CMD and cat to view? Below isn't working:
`CMD ["cat","$HOME/kernel-info"]`. I also tried including the shell in CMD directive, `CMD ["/bin/sh","-c","$HOME/kernel-info"]` - it isnt working either.

Comment: Since you use an environment variable, you again need a shell. I'd use `CMD cat $HOME/kernel-info`, but you can also do `CMD [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "cat $HOME/kernel-info" ]`

Comment: I used `CMD cat $HOME/kernel-info` but when I build the image and run the container, it does not show the output from CMD. When I open an interactive session, I see the file exists. What I want is, when the container runs, it should display the `cat` output and exit.

Comment: Are you running the container under a different user than root? For it to work, the same user that builds the image must be the same as when running it, because $HOME needs to have the same value.

Comment: My container is on a Ubuntu vm. On my VM, I tried switching to root and then running the container, still didnt display the output (I can see the file exists under $HOME/kernel-info). When I login to the container, it logs me in as the root user as well. So far, it has been the same user (me) building the image and running the container.

Comment: I think you should make a new question about this and include a complete Dockerfile that illustrates your problem

Answer (score -1):

To use a different shell, other than `/bin/sh`, use the exec form passing in the desired shell. For example:

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo hello"]
```